# Google Cloud API grammar

Tags: c#, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Using this code I've found on a youtube video (don't know if i'm able to post) :

```
if (File.Exists("audio.raw"))
{
    var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
    var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
    {
        Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
        SampleRateHertz = 16000,
        LanguageCode = "iw",
    }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile("audio.raw"));

    textBox1.Text = "";

    foreach (var result in response.Results)
    {
        foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + alternative.Transcript;
        }
    }

    if(textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
        textBox1.Text = "No Data ";
    StreamingMicRecognizeAsync(10);
}
else
{
    textBox1.Text = "Audio File Missing ";
}
```

I was able to create a speech recognition based on google cloud api.

However, i can't find a way for creating a grammar this way, therefore i'm looking for suggestions.

How can i create a grammar filtering for google api?

Is there maybe a project somebody made, or some apis that are already doing that (for example : entering a main string of "one", "two", "three" and then if you input for example "tu" it'll output "two", if you input "today" it'll output that nothing fits etc, like microsoft's grammar)

I've read about SpeechContexts but it's read only in c# and i really couldn't get something to work.

Any suggestions?

Edit :

Also how can I use it offline? would be great... or at least make it faster.

I tried the streaming option but its not accurate at all.

Comment: "Also how can I use it offline? would be great... or at least make it faster." You can't - it's a cloud service, therefore not available offline. I don't know what you mean by "Its not accurate at all" for the streaming option - it's worked okay for me. Not sure what you mean about SpeechContext being read-only, either... it's not. I'm adding an example in my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've replied to your comment, please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to add `SpeechContext` to your request, just add instances to the `RecognitionConfig`'s `SpeechContexts` property:

```
var context = new SpeechContext { Phrases = { "first", "second" } };
var config = new RecognitionConfig()
{
    Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
    SampleRateHertz = 16000,
    LanguageCode = "iw",
    SpeechContexts = { context }
};
```

(In general, the *properties* in protobuf representing maps and lists are read-only, but you can add to them - either calling `Add` explicitly, or using collection initializers as above.)

Comment: i had an error of the variable being read only... nevermind i solved it, your comment helped me with that too.
for the second thing though, i know that the cloud service is an online service obviously, but for phone for example there is google now, which for my knowledge is an offline service. isn't there something samiliar to that (by any name) for the desktops?

Comment: @matan: I believe there are whole different SDKs for Google Assistant etc. I don't know of an offline equivalent of the Google Speech API.